# How to convert view object to my layout in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to access `page.questionTextView` in `setAnswer` function

```
//Create the given page (indicated by position)
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_question, null)
    page.questionTextView.text = "hi"

    //Add the page to the front of the queue
    (container as ViewPager).addView(page, 0)
    return page
}

private fun setAnswer(page: View){
    //how to access page.questionTextView
}
```

Comment: You can declare page as global variable 
`private lateinit var page: View`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: i use "with" method to access to page.questionTextView

```
private fun setAnswer(page: View){
    with(page){
        questionTextView.text = "hi"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the page variable at the top level i.e. directly inside the package. By default, if you do not specify a visibility modifier, your variable will be public. This means that it will be accessible everywhere (within the package).

More info about visibility in kotlin : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create the **page** var **global** to your class you can initialize it within your **instantiateItem** function and use it to access your view from the **setAnswer** function.

Try this

```
private lateinit var page: View
//Create the given page (indicated by position)
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_question, null)
    page.questionTextView.text = "hi"

    //Add the page to the front of the queue
    (container as ViewPager).addView(page, 0)
    return page
}

private fun setAnswer(){
    //how to access page.questionTextView
    page.questionTextView.text = "your answer"
}
```